# How to get Id of focused element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My title might not really express what i want to achieve so i hope reader can go through my question first.
I have many input on my page with different id, i want to get the ID of the particular input that get user focus and fire an event when this input loses focus. i can achieve this by explicitly state the ID and attach onblur event handler to it but this will result in writing a bulk of codes as i have too many input on the same page. now i have this below code

```
var \$Title = $('#draft-product_title')
        \$Title.on('blur',function(event){
            eventId = event.target.id;
            draftEventHandler(\$Title,eventId);
        });
```

this is one of my input and i have more that 30 input so i have to make copy of it 30 time which is so crazy i need a way to make it so flexible, i tried this too but no luck

```
var \$selectorId;
$('body').on('click',function(event) {
            \$focusElementId = document.activeElement.id;
             \$selectorId = ('#'+\$focusElementId)
            console.log(\$selectorId);
         });

        \$selectorId.on('blur',function(event){
            eventId = event.target.id;
            draftEventHandler(\$selectorId,eventId);
        });
```

but this code error selector id not define but the `console.log()` as it define
any help on how to make this work, am also open to any other idea, thaks

Comment: Does `$(this).attr('id');` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `:input` selector to select all `input` element

`this` context in `event-handler` will be `element` on which `event` is `invoked` hence `this.id` will return `id` property of the `element` or `""`(empty)

```js
$(':input').on('focus', function() {
  console.log(this.id);
}).on('blur', function() {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="name" value="Mickey">
  <br>Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br>
  <br>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event to the focused element. or just get it, with `:focus` selector.

```js
(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ":focus", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  })
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" type="test1" value="id1">
<input id="id2" type="test2" value="id2">
```